# How do you pronounce the הוי״ה in hataras nedarim (annulment of vows) before Rosh HaShanah?  

Tags: rosh-hashanah-new-year, hebrew, pronunciation, nedarim-shevuot

In the siddurs I've seen, we ask for annulment for vows made "with the name הוי״ה ".  That word is left unvowelized.  How is it pronounced?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually I hear it pronounced "havaya."  I think we refer to the four-letter name (yud-kay-vov-kay) as "havaya" ("existence") because it has the same letters and same root.

Has anyone heard otherwise?

Comment: You are correct. My source is purely mimetic from reliable Jews who actually had mesorah.

Comment: Do any siddurim vowelize it?  Do they leave it unvowelized so people know it's an anagram of the (unvowelized) name of G-d?